# React axios ReactJS AXIOS post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

console error ->
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOfUV.png

```
   axios
      .post("https://bootcamp-2022.devtest.ge/api/application", {
token: "7e475dfc-0daa-4108-81c8-d6c62a3df4ca",
first_name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PersonalInfo").first_name),
last_name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PersonalInfo").last_name),
email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PersonalInfo").email),
skills: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("techskill").skills),
work_preference: JSON.parse(
localStorage.getItem("covid").work_preference),


.then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
```

Comment: That error is telling you that one of your `JSON.parse` calls isnt parsing valid json. `localStorage` works with strings so `localStorage.getItem("covid").work_preference` and others are going to give you `undefined`. Probably meant to put the `)` before the property access eg `parse(localStorage.getItem("covid")).work_preference`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error metioned you have an error on your json

This is your current code

```
first_name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PersonalInfo").first_name)
```

This is how it should be

```
first_name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PersonalInfo")).first_name
```

And you might want to hide the api and the token .